# How to represent a user login form in a template? (django)

Tags: python, django

Currently I have the

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

but I'm confused as to how you can use this to create a form for users to create themselves in the database and then login.

I found this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator in a similar  question asked on here. But I really confused on how the user thing works. So any examples of possible templates variable to represent the login would be excellent. also any explanation of what's going on. I find it hard to understand when there isn't hadlry any documentation that's written like a user will be using it and not code that it written to be executed inside a shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a user form you can manually create a form with the fields you would like to save for the user, requiring at least a username and password

`<form action="/signup/" method="POST">`

`Username: <input type="text" name="username" />`

`Password: <input type="text" name="password" />`

`</form>`

then in the view this points towards you can capture the input like:

```
def signup(request):
  username = request.POST['username']
  password = request.POST['password']
  User.objects.create_user(username=username, email='', password=password)
```

Django provides a shortcut to do this though, so you don't have to worry about creating your own html forms or validating forms! It will do everything for you!  They are called Modelforms.
https://doc.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Regarding the `login_required` decorator, it makes sure that the user is logged before being allowed to access that particular view.  If they are not, they are redirected to the page in your `LOGIN_URL` in your settings.py file.

The first step to learning how users work is to read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator from top to bottom and do the code tutorials.

Make sure to include a [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) token on your manually created forms as well

Answer (score 1):

you can overwrite the login form like:

```
class MyLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
'''Extend login form'''
    username = forms.CharField(
        label=_("username"),
        max_length=30,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'title': '请输入您的域名！',
            'id': 'id_username',
            'name': 'username'
        }))
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("password"), 
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
             'title':'请输入域密码！',
             'id':'id_password',
             'name':'password'
        }))
```

here you can have you own validations for the login form.

and then in the urls.py:

```
 (r'^accounts/login/$', 
      'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
      {'template_name': 'login.html','authentication_form':MyLoginForm,}),
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Just a friendly hint: if a preview shows scrollbars for your answer, you should break up the lines to make it more readable.  Readable answers get more upvotes.